# Changing row value according to a condition not working in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
 TYPE              NAME          IS_MAIN
 PPRTYPE           TIME            0
 PPRTYPE           SIGHT           0
 PPRTYPE           SIGHT           1
 PNRDTL            NOT FOUND       1
 PPRTYPE           SIGHT           0 
 PPRTYPE           TIME            1
```

If `TYPE` is `PPRTYPE` and `NAME` is `SIGHT` and `IS_MAIN` is `1`
then the `NAME` of  `TYPE` `PNRDTL` should be changed to `'NOT APPLICABLE'` if `IS_MAIN` is `1`.

*Note*: `IS_MAIN = 1` for any TYPE would come once only.

Code:

```
temp = df.loc[(df['IS_MAIN'] == 1) & (df['TYPE'] == 'PPRTYPE'), 'NAME']
temp = temp.reset_index(drop=True)
temp = temp[0]
if (temp == 'SIGHT'):
     df.loc[(df['TYPE'] == 'PNRDTL') & (df['IS_MAIN'] == 1) , 'NAME'] = 'NOT APPLICABLE'
```

The problem I'm facing is that

```
(df['TYPE'] == 'PNRDTL') & (df['IS_MAIN'] == 1)
```

is not getting any value, so the value is not getting changed.

I would be happy if someone could findout the mistake I'm commiting or tell me any work around.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is `print (df.dtypes)` ? Maybe need change `(df['IS_MAIN'] == '1')` if `1` is string

Comment: What name should be changed? reading your sentence I get confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me working:

```
#if `1` is integer
mask = (df['IS_MAIN'] == 1) & (df['TYPE'] == 'PPRTYPE')
#if 1 is string
#mask = (df['IS_MAIN'] == '1') & (df['TYPE'] == 'PPRTYPE')

if (df.loc[mask, 'NAME'].iloc[0] == 'SIGHT'):
    df.loc[mask , 'NAME'] = 'NOT APPLICABLE'
print (df)
      TYPE            NAME  IS_MAIN
0  PPRTYPE            TIME        0
1  PPRTYPE           SIGHT        0
2  PPRTYPE  NOT APPLICABLE        1
3   PNRDTL       NOT FOUND        1
4  PPRTYPE           SIGHT        0
5  PPRTYPE  NOT APPLICABLE        1
```